# Как сделать чтобы объект, выходящий за границы body не создавал боковой скролл на мобильном

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Внизу привел пример кода.
Набросал небольшое мобильное меню с переключателем, при клике на который область контента сдвигается бок, а слева выезжает мобильное меню.

при этом на мобильном устройстве появляется боковой скролл, думал что проблему решит , если я к `body` напишу `overflow-x: hidden`, и помогло но только на ПК,а на мобильнике по-прежнему можно сдвигать контент пальцем обратно.

Знаю, что можно дополнительно задать `position: fixed`, но это не мой случай так как иконка переключателя меню предполагается что будет тоже фиксированная.
 ТО есть при прокрутке, оставаться в левом верхнем углу.

При этом, при клике на нее контент будет дергаться и и прокручиваться к началу страницы. 
В общем этот костыль не мой случай.

Поэтому хотелось бы знать, как можно избавиться от бокового сролла на мобильном устройстве. Без использования `position: fixed` у `body`

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.menu, .content').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.menu, .content').addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 500ms;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.content.active {
  transform: translate(290px, 0);
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 290px;
  background: #5fba7d;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: 500ms;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-inner">
    <h2>Меню</h2>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/> ссылка
    <br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  Это область контента текст текст текст
</div>
```

Comment: overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: @PROPHESSOR именно так и прописано, браузер google chrome сенсорные устройства спокойно двигают body вбок когда меню активно контент уезжает за пределы body, при этом не важно как я задаю смещение margin, left, transform...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Добавил дополнительную обертку всему содержимому.
2. Изменил свойство transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
3. Зафиксировал меню в одном положении.
   Внешне изменения практически незаметны, но это позволило избавиться от бокового скролла. Скорее всего достаточно выполнить первое действие

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.content').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.content').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.content').addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 500ms;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 1;
}

.content.active {
  transform: translate3d(290px, 0, 0);
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 290px;
  background: #5fba7d;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  transition: 500ms;
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-inner">
      <h2>Меню</h2>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/> ссылка
      <br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="toggle">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    Это область контента текст текст текст
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

у меня вроде не двигается, ну ка проверь

```js
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  if ($('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.menu, .content').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.menu, .content').addClass('active');
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
  transition: 500ms;
  transform: translateX(0);
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%
}

.content.active {
  transform: translateX(290px);
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 290px;
  background: #5fba7d;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 500ms;
}

.menu.active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.toggle {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-inner">
    <h2>Меню</h2>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/> ссылка
    <br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>ссылка<br/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  Это область контента текст текст текст
</div>
```